# wxWidgets: Periodically redraw image in wxFrame

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have a MainFrame and to set a background image I have implemented my own `OnPaint()` function.

```
OnPaint(wxPaintEvent& roEvent)
{
    if (!m_oBackgorund1.IsOk() || !m_oBackgorund2.IsOk())
        return;
    wxPaintDC paintDC(this);

    switch (roEvent.GetId())
    {
    case 0:
        paintDC.DrawBitmap(m_oBackgorund1, 0, 0);
        break;
    default:
        paintDC.DrawBitmap(m_oBackgorund2, 0, 0);
        break;
    }
}
```

The two bitmaps are correctly loaded previously. When starting my application the image `m_oBackgorund2` is set as a background because the event's `GetId()` returns -201.

After that I start a thread that fires an event with either `0` or `1` as Id

```
{
    nId = !nId;
    wxPaintEvent oPaintEvent;
    oPaintEvent.SetId(nId);
    wxPostEvent(GetParent(), oPaintEvent);
}
```

The `OnPaint` is called correnty by that event and the bitmap is set according to the Id. However, the changes do not show in the UI. 
If I call `Refresh()` in the `OnPaint()` the background image is painted voer everything else.

How can I update the Backgorund image of the `wxFrame` without having it paint over all other UI elements?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your approach because what you're doing is not going to work.

The basic problem is that you can't post paint events (or any other event processed by the underlying GUI layer) from your own code. These events are generated by the GUI library you use itself (i.e. Windows, GTK+ or Cocoa) and the windows have to be repainted when they get them, but artificially creating such events doesn't make the window repaint itself. The only way to do this is to call `Refresh()` on it and `Refresh()`, like all the GUI functions, can only be called from the main GUI thread.

So if you really want to use threads (and for what you're doing a timer would seem like a much more natural choice), you must post a custom event to the main thread which would then refresh the window which would then repaint itself.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. How could a timer appraoch look like? Wouldnt the timer need to continue running in some thread?         By the way , my Thread is started from within the panel which has the background.

Comment: Look at `wxEVT_TIMER` documentation. And timer don't use threads because the underlying GUI has special support for them.